# C# how to separate a string by numbering (1. 2. ...)

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have this string "1: This 2: Is 3: A 4: Test" and would like to split it based on the numbering, like this:

"1: This"
"2: Is"
"3: A"
"4: Test"

I think this should be possible with a regular expression, but unfortunately I don't understand much about it.

This: `string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");` just splits the numbers without the colon and the content behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a capture group `()` like this:

```cs
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"(\d+:)");
```

the captured values will be added to the array too. Then all that is left to do is to merge every first value with every second value (we skip index 0 as it is empty):

```cs
List<string> values = new();
for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i += 2)
{
    values.Add(result[i] + result[i + 1]); 
}
```

There are probably cleaner ways to do this, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```cs
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?!^)(?=(?<!\d)\d+:)")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sV7Dh/1). Note that the `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind is necessary when you have bullet point with two or more digits. *Details*:

- `(?!^)` - not at the start of string
- `(?=(?<!\d)\d+:)` - the position that is immediately followed with one or more digits (not preceded with any digit) and a `:` char.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\D+` matches 1 or more non digits, and will therefore match `: This` to split on.

Instead of using split, you can also match the parts:

```
\b[0-9]+:.*?(?=\b[0-9]+:|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[0-9]+:` Match 1+ digits and `:`
- `.*?` Match as least as possible characters
- `(?=\b[0-9]+:|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either 1+ digits and `:` or the end of the string to the right

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%2b%3a.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cb%5b0-9%5d%2b%3a%7c%24%29&i=1%3a+This+2%3a+Is+3%3a+A+4%3a+Test)

Example in C#:

```
string str = "1: This 2: Is 3: A 4: Test";
string pattern = @"\b[0-9]+:.*?(?=\b[0-9]+:|$)";

MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);
string[] result = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToArray();

Array.ForEach(result, Console.WriteLine);
```

Output

```
1: This 
2: Is 
3: A 
4: Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by space then take each second item. Because if you define the word as something delimited by (white)space, '1.' or '2.' are words too, and you aren't able to distinguish them.

```
string[] split = content.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] result = new string[split.Length / 2];
for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i = i + 2) result[i / 2] = split[i];
```